# How to use a getter to return a read-only nested object?

Tags: javascript, getter

Imagine an object (for a slider) with a nested private object property for autoscroll:

```
let slider = {
    slides: ... ,
    arrows: ... ,
    someMethods(),

    _autoScroll: {
        on: true/false,
        delay: in ms,
        run(),
        stop(),
        somethingElse...
    }
}
```

I define a getter/setter, like:

```
Object.defineProperty(slider, 'autoScroll', {
        get() {
            return this._autoScroll; (****)
        },
        set(value) {
            if (value.on !== 'undefined') this._autoScroll.on = !!value.on;
            let a = Number(value.delay);
            if ( isFinite(a) && !isNaN(a) ) this._autoScroll.delay = a;
        }
    });
```

As you see I want to give an opportunity to set the properties `on` and `delay` like this:

```
slider.autoScroll = {on:true, delay:2000};
```

The problem is that in the line (****) I can get the original nested object `_autoScroll` and I can also change its properties or even add some new:

```
slider.autoScroll.on = 'some Crap';
slider.autoScroll.newProperty = 111;
```

Which changes the original object, but I would like to see the whole object but in a read-only mode.

One of the possible ideas is to use `JSON.stringify` in the getter, but it's not what I want. Another option I thought of was to return a clone object with something like:

```
Object.defineProperties({}, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(obj));
```

or just Object.assign(). But it's too heavy and unnecessary, it's not effective!

What do you think, is there any method or algorithm to accomplish this effectively, quickly, beautifully? What are the best practices? Maybe I shouldn't show the whole object with all its properties at all as it is an anti-pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Object.assign` method you mentioned looks quite concise to me:

```
return Object.assign({}, this._autoScroll);
```

You could do it even more concisely with spread:

```
return { ...this._autoScroll };
```

Note that if the object properties change, the caller of `.autoScroll` will have to call it again, to get the updated object data.